# Creating a sound file composed of smaller files

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, mediarecorder

I am writing an app that takes Morse code, and plays it over the speakers.

Currently I am able to record audio over the microphone using this code:

```
public void startRecord() throws Exception{
        if (record != null){
            record.release();
        }

        File fileOut = new File(FILE);
        if (fileOut != null){
            fileOut.delete(); // delete any existing file at that location.
        }

        record = new MediaRecorder();
        record.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        record.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        record.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        record.setOutputFile(FILE);

        record.prepare();
        record.start();
    }
```

and i am able to generate morse code in a string formatted like this:

```
"-.... .---- -.... -.-. -.... ..... --... ---.."
```

I can iterate over this string using a for loop such as this:

```
char[] chars = message.toCharArray();
for (char ch : chars) {
    //add to audio file
}
```

But I am not sure how to create a file out of strung together wav files. Ive seen some posts that mention setting the audio source as a file from the device, but Im not sure how to pick and choose which file and where to insert them, or how to compile it all into a single audio file.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  Please [edit] your question to be far more specific about what help you need.

Comment: Couldn't you just have isolated dash, dot sounds and then play them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new sound file and playing that, it would probably be easier to just play each sound individually and when that sound finishes, you play the next sound, or you wait for a brief pause if it's a space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this the harder way. What if you were to simply have the program read the first letter, play the appropriate sound, do the same for the next letter and so on throughout the text. I believe it is much simpler but if you are really set on trying to put it into one file you could have the program make an empty file but in the name it sets have the extension `.wav` or `.mp3` and do research into how they are encoded.